# Dynamically returning SOQL data to lightning community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I have a requirement where I need to populate data dynamically into my community page through my apex class.

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<ZenObject__c> getZenObjectnew(){
    // ZenObject__c ZenObjsnew=DataBase.query('SELECT ZenLms_Name_del__c,ZenLms_SubText__c FROM ZenObject__c order By CreatedDate desc limit 1');
    List<ZenObject__c> ZenObjsnew=[SELECT ZenLms_Name_del__c,ZenLms_SubText__c FROM ZenObject__c order By CreatedDate desc limit 1];
    return ZenObjsnew; 
}
```

In this method I am returning some fields to my community page in a lightning component.As i create the record in my salesforce object, the query should fetch that record and immediately show it in my community page.
I tried the above query but when ever I am creating new records it is replacing previously created records.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="ClassName">
    <aura:attribute name="ZenObjsnew" type="ZenObject__c[]" />
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap content-box">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.ZenObjsnew}" var="zenobjsnew">
            <div class="slds-size--12-of-12 slds-medium-size--3-of-12">
                <img src="{!v.imagepath1}" alt="{!v.imagetext1}" />
            </div>
            <div class="slds-size--12-of-12 slds-medium-size--9-of-12">
                <h4 class="liheading">                     
                   <div aura:id="{!zenobjsnew.Id}">
                      <a href="{!v.linkpath1}">{!zenobjsnew.ZenLms_Name_del__c}</a>
                      <p class="text-limit">{!zenobjsnew.ZenLms_SubText__c}</p><br/><br/>
                   </div>   
                </h4>
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

This is the component in which I am displaying the records. There is something definitely wrong in my query.

**Edited**

//Js controller

```
getZenObjectnew : function(component) {
    var action = component.get("c.getZenObjectnew");      
   // var self = this;
    action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
        //alert('getZen1');
        var state = actionResult.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            alert('frth');
            var resultObj = actionResult.getReturnValue();
            //var data=JSON.stringify(resultObj);
            alert(resultObj);
            var arr=component.get("v.ZenObjsnew");
            alert('arr line'+arr);
            arr.push(resultObj[0]);
            alert(arr);
              //component.set("v.ZenObjsnew", arr);
            component.set("v.ZenObjsnew", actionResult.getReturnValue()); 
            //alert(actionResult.getReturnValue());
            }

    });


        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

Comment: Chances are that you are over-writing the `v.ZenObjsnew` attribute in lightning component controller with the returned value from the Apex Controller. So if you paste your lightning controller code as well, we can confirm.

Comment: @SantanuHalder Thanks for reply..But v.ZenObjsnewis getting data from apex class only.

Comment: That's what I said, I am guessing you are overwritting the existing value of `ZenObjsnew` while saving the data from apex class. Paste your Lightning JS controller in the question.

Comment: @SantanuHalder.. Yaa when ever i am creating new data it is getting over ridden.But that should not happen.

Answer (score 3):

The fix is simple - you need to **PUSH** new items to your array, rather than adding a new array - it overwrites it every time.

Also, before you push, make sure that you have a valid object before pushing.

Inside your calling method change it to something like this:

```
if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
    var resultArr = actionResult.getReturnValue();
    if (resultArr.length > 0 && resultArr[0].Id){ //or some other property that verifies success
      var arr = component.get("v.ZenObjsnew");
      arr.push(resultArr[0]);
      component.set("v.ZenObjsnew", arr);
    } 
}
```

**EDIT - Here is the entire function**

```
getZenObjectnew: function(component) {
  var action = component.get("c.getZenObjectnew");
  var self = this;
  action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
    var state = actionResult.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
      var resultArr = actionResult.getReturnValue();
      if (resultArr.length > 0 && resultArr[0].Id){ //or some other property that verifies success
        var arr = component.get("v.ZenObjsnew");
        arr.push(resultArr[0]);
        component.set("v.ZenObjsnew", arr);
      } 
    }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

I don't even know if you are call the function, as you don't have the `$A.enqueueAction(action);`. Also, in your component, what calls this?

Comment: Solved the issue.Actually we cannot get single record every time.I changed the query and removed the limit of 1.Which will fetch all the records and every time i create new record the record will not be over ridden